# Migrating Database in a N-Tier Application with Entity Framework Codefirst

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

I'm trying to create database with Entity Framework Code first approach in my layered project structure. I use standart code-first console commands;

- **enable-migrations** => ok
- **add-migration Init** => problem: it doesn't produce migration code, there are just up and down methods
- **update-database** => nothing to do; there is no change

How can I execute this migration in layered structure? How are migration changes tracked?

You can check my code simply on github: https://github.com/srht/layeredIdentity

In the code on github; it once created the init migration but again after I deleted the database it didn't create such initial migration code.

Answer (score 0):

> ...there are just up and down methods...

That is how a migration works, when you do `Update-Database` there is always an implicit source migration and target migration, so EF applies incrementally all Up methods of the migrations between those two source and target ones (or the Down methods if you are downgrading your database). EF generates the SQL code to be applied for each migration, if you want to see it you can run `Update-Database` with the `-script` parameter. This way no changes are executed and you can check the generated SQL.

> How are migration changes tracked?

There is a table named `__MigrationsHistory`. When you run `Update-Database` EF inserts in that table a record for each migration that is applied. Next time you change the code of your model classes you have to generate a new incremental migration by running `Add-Migration YourNewMigrationName`. When you run `Add-Migration` EF detects the incremental changes in your model since the last previous migration, and generates a new migration including only those changes. Migration file names include a timestamp so that they can be ordered in time.

If you run `Update-Database` and nothing happens it is because your database is up to date, all pending migrations have been applied. You should get some message in the console telling "No explicit migrations to apply" or something similar. If you get some other message about still having pending migrations, or some error message, then something went wrong.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx) you have more info from Msdn about how migrations work.

Comment: So is there any difference for a layered solution? Are there any additional things to run migrations? Because standart migration commands not create migration code; up and down methods come out blank. As you mentioned i had deleted migration table in database not to track and start over. But it didn't produce the migration code.